# How can I pull from a Heroku repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is really strange, but in my Rails app, a hidden element is displaying perfectly in a certain viewport on Heroku, and yet locally the element is staying hidden.

1) What could be causing this discrepancy between Heroku and the local server?
2) Can I pull from the repo and test locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Maybe because it runs in production on heroku?
2) Your local repo should be the same as you pushed it from your local repository to heroku, but you can test the code on heroku by checking out the remote branch.

```
git checkout heroku/master
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare what is on Heroku vs your local branch with `git log`.

```
git log master..heroku/master
```